# Can I claim miles if I bought the tickets but didn't take the flight?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs, miles-and-more

Due to odd circumstances I didn't have a chance to take a flight. I already bought the tickets and I wasn't able to cancel anything.

Can I still request miles (Miles & More)?

Comment: Did you check in online?

Comment: @FooBar It doesn't matter whether you checked in or not; the airline knows whether you actually took the flight or not based on whether your boarding pass was scanned or not. I'd wager there isn't a single frequent flyer program anywhere in the world that gives you miles for flights you don't take, as a matter of policy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No**

This is specified in the [Terms and conditions of Miles and More](https://www.miles-and-more.com/online/portal/mam/at/program/information?nodeid=2522607&l=en&cid=18001).

Specifically (emphasis mine), section 2.3.2:

> For each *actually flown* segment of a fully paid scheduled flight operated by Lufthansa, a joint operator or a Miles & More partner company, the member’s account will be credited with miles – subject to Sections 2.3.6 and 2.3.7.

and section 2.3.6:

> Any mileage credit is also excluded for *unused*, reimbursed, lapsed or unlawfully obtained documents (tickets, coupons, etc.). The same applies in other cases of *non-utilization* or the refund of the service qualifying for earning miles.

Comment: Beat me by 22 seconds ...

Comment: and you beat my comment by 10 seconds ! :)

Answer (score 9):

Sadly no, here are the relevant parts from the Miles & More [Terms and Conditions](https://www.miles-and-more.com/online/portal/mam/de/program/information?nodeid=2522607&l=en&cid=18002) (bolding mine):

> **2.3.1 General provisions for earning miles**
>   Members can start earning miles after membership commences. Miles can only be credited to the member’s individual mileage account for **services the member personally utilized**. When using the services of the Miles & More partner companies, the beneficiary of the Miles & More must be a cardholder to ensure that the miles can be credited. [ ... ]
>
> **2.3.2 Special provisions for flights**
>   For each **actually flown** segment of a fully paid scheduled flight operated by Lufthansa, a joint operator or a Miles & More partner company, the member’s account will be credited with miles – subject to Sections 2.3.6 and 2.3.7.
>
> **2.3.6 Exclusions from mileage credit**
>   [ ... ] Any mileage credit is also excluded for unused, reimbursed, lapsed or unlawfully obtained documents (tickets, coupons, etc.). The same applies in other cases of non-utilization or the refund of the service qualifying for earning miles. [ ... ]

Even though you didn't take the flight, you may still be able to change it (rather than cancel it) to some point in the future when you may use. And even if it can't be cancelled it may be possible to get some money back from the taxes included in the ticket price. But, you'll not get any miles for it.

Answer (score 3):

While in general the answer is no as correctly stated in the other answers, there is one cheat/exception: Lufthansa sells tickets for trains operated by Deutsche Bahn and you can earn miles for those. Since not being controlled on the train is possible, you can claim miles for that segment, as long as you have checked in online before "boarding", even without taking the journey. However it would still  be imperative to take the attached flight.